# Invalid Syntax: import TextBlob in python 2.6.6

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have Python 2.6.6 installed

I downloaded the textblob package from [Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textblob)

I installed the package using the following command

```
python setup.py install
```

Inside my site-packages I can see the following egg

```
textblob-0.11.1-py2.6.egg
```

However when I am importing the package, it gives me the following error

```
> from textblob import TextBlob
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/textblob-0.11.1-py2.6.egg/textblob/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .blob import TextBlob, Word, Sentence, Blobber, WordList
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/textblob-0.11.1-py2.6.egg/textblob/blob.py", line 28, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk-3.2.1-py2.6.egg/nltk/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk-3.2.1-py2.6.egg/nltk/collocations.py", line 38, in <module>
    from nltk.util import ngrams
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nltk-3.2.1-py2.6.egg/nltk/util.py", line 1361
    d = {k: _default_to_regular(v) for k, v in d.items()}
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there anything missing here?

**UPDATE 1:**

I installed successfully textblob 0.8.4

While installing NLTK 2.0.5, I am getting following error

command:

```
python setup.py install
```

Error:

```
`Installed /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.21-py2.6.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 69, in <module>
    test_suite = 'nltk.test.simple',
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 73, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 101, in do_egg_install
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 345, in run

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 565, in easy_install

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 617, in install_item

  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 664, in process_distribution

TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
`
```

Comment: Did you install nltk separately?  Where did you install it from?

Comment: yes I installed nltk 3.2.1 but now I have deleted it. I am installing 2.0.5 but facing issues in it

Comment: See my answer. You also need to downgrade TextBlob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nltk-3.2.1` doesn't support Python 2.6 (the `SyntaxError` is due to the fact that [dictionary comprehension was not yet introduced to Python until 2.7](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)). Either upgrading your Python to 2.7 or downgrading `nltk` to `2.0.5`:

```
pip install nltk==2.0.5
```

Edit: After researched `TextBlob`'s `setup.py` and `CHANGELOG.rst` files, it turns out you probably also [need to downgrade `TextBlob` to `0.8.4`](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/0.11.1/CHANGELOG.rst#090-2014-09-15) to avoid the dependency of `nltk>=3.0`, if you decided not to upgrade your Python.

Edit 2: To solve the setuptools error, use `python distribute_setup.py` instead.

Edit 3: You don't need to install `nltk` if you installed `TextBlob <= 0.8.4`. Because it contains a vendorized version of `nltk`.

Comment: I think you're right, but it seems odd that there is a file called `nI ltk-3.2.1-py2.6.egg` if that NLTK version doesn't support that Python version.

Comment: I can't upgrade python

Comment: @Hardik then downgrade both `nltk` and `textblob`.

Comment: installed textblob 0.8.4, downloaded and unziped tar for nltk 2.0.5, then tried installing nltk like this `python setup.py install` it gives error

Comment: @Hardik: it's a new problem. Try `python distribute_setup.py`. You should upgrade your toolchain someday. The package `distribute` is deprecated for years.

Comment: Running the above comment resolved both my issues.. you guys are awesome. God bless you